# Azure mobile app Nodejs back end Invalid data type provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to insert a row in the table.
here are steps what I did :

I run Create table Statement in database to create table test

```
    Create table test4
(
    id int primary key identity (1, 1),
    name nvarchar(100)
)
```

then I go to the app service editor and Create file javascript with the name is test4.js

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
```

then I go to my API and do the insert logic :

```
var test = {
            name: "test country1",

        };

    req.azureMobile.tables('test4')
        .insert(test)
        .then(() => res.send({
        status: config.get('statusResponse.success'),
        token: 'token'
    })).catch(error => {console.log("error " + error)});
```

I don't know why I got this error.

> error Error: Invalid data type provided

**i Update my Question**

when I create a table using Easy tables of Azure I can insert records into the table but I want to use the exists table that I created with my tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error Error: Invalid data type provided

From the statement you provided to create the table:

```html
Create table test4
(
    id int primary key identity (1, 1),
    name nvarchar(100)
)
```

As [30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 6 – PERSONAL TABLES](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/) mentioned about the system fields:

> **The ‘id’ field is a string** – it can be anything, but it has to be unique as the id is a primary key. If you don’t specify it, Azure Mobile Apps will assign the string representation of a v4 GUID to this field.